# Spring REST service to consume and produce both HTML form POST and AJAX/JSON in a single method

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to teach myself Spring by creating a very simple web application. I have a class to create "Note" objects:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/notes")
public class NoteRestController {

    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2JsonView jsonView;

    [...]

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
    public ModelAndView create(final Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute final Note note, final BindingResult result) {

        ModelAndView mav;

                // how can I test the request source?
                if (<requesting from HTML FORM>) {
                        // return jsonView
                mav = new ModelAndView(jsonView);
                } else {
                        // return JSP view
                mav = new ModelAndView("note", "model", model);
                }

        model.addAttribute("note", note);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("errors", result.getAllErrors());

            // on error, redirect back to note page with form
            // return new ModelAndView("note/note", "model", model);
            return mav;
        }

        note.setId(daoService.createNote(note));

        return mav;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to use a single method (like the above) to handle requests from both an AJAX post AND a HTML form post. If triggered by AJAX I would like to return JSON (with validation errors if present), and if it is triggered by a HTML form, I would like to return to the JSP using the form taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

and show validation errors next to input fields using  e.g.

```
<form:errors path="title" cssClass="errorMessage"></form:errors>
```

Is this possible, or should I be creating two controllers; one for the REST/JSON, and one for HTML/form? Maybe there is something I can pass into the method that can be interrogated to determibne the request source, but I can't see it right now.

**What would be the "best practice" in this case?**

**EDIT 1:**
Trying answer from @ring-bearer first as it allows for the same URL pattern, but having issues.

Using methods:

```
// used to handle JSON/XML
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody Note create(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute final Note note, final BindingResult result) {
            [...]
}

// used to handle form view
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createForView(final Model model,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute final Note note, final BindingResult result) {
            [...]
}
```

Interestingly, the HTML form submission, *still* gets handled by `create()` and not `createForView()`. After looking at the form submission request headers, I see that this Accept header:

```
    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

By adding `produces = "text/html"` to `@RequestMapping` on `createForView()`, all 3 scenarios work (form, AJAX/JSON, AJAX/XML).

Is this normal, or am I still missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using "content negotiation". Spring MVC needs to be enabled for content negotiation using a "contentNegotiationManager" definition. It can be set up using Java or XML configuration. The configuration will centrally manage media type mappings(json, xml etc). Once that is set up, a controller class can be built to cater to both JSON and View(HTML). Below is a generic example(uncompiled), it should be easy to refactor your class to similar structure to avoid violation of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
@Controller
class ReportController{

   //1- Method for JSON/marshalling types(XML)
    @RequestMapping(value="/report", produces={"application/xml", "application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody List<ReportPara> generateReport(Principal principal) {
        return reportService.generateReport(principal);
    }

    //2- For View technologies ( Eg:JSP HTML)
    @RequestMapping("/report")
    public String generateReportForView(Model model, Principal principal) {
        model.addAttribute( generateReport(principal) );

        // Return the view to use for rendering the response
        return ¨reports/main¨;
    }
}
```

Which of the two `@RequestMapping` methods will execute? It is determined by content negotiation definition. Eg: URLs such as report.xml or report.json map to the first method, any other URLs ending in report.anything map to the second.

Comment: progress, but the `createForView()` method doesn't get called for regular form submission, instead, it is handled by `create()` due to the request Accept header added to question

Comment: Not quite sure if `produces=text/html` is required on the "forView" method - as others are annotated explicitly. Looks like you already got it working by adding it to "forView" method as well - which makes me think that is required. Most reliable example https://github.com/paulc4/mvc-content-neg/blob/master/src/main/java/rewardsonline/accounts/AccountsController.java does not however seem to use it

Answer (score 1):

The following will be easier to maintain:

```
@Controller
class NoteController {
  @Autowired NoteService service;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/note")
  public ModelAndView createFromForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid Note note, BindingResult result) {
    return new ModelAndView("note", create(note));
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/note")
  @ResponseBody
  public Note createFromApi(@RequestBody Note note) {
    return create(note);
  }

  private Note create(Note note) {
    return service.create(note);
  }
}
```